# MySQL - Select from 2 tables where couple of columns in result should be based on conditional statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Dear MySQL/SQL experts,

Requesting your help with the following scenario.  I have 2 tables as noted below.

```
TABLE1
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+----------------+
|uid | active_hour_start   | active_hour_end     | activity_name  | activity_value |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+----------------+
| 01 | 2018-06-17 13:00:00 | 2018-06-17 14:00:00 | activity1      |             10 |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 13:00:00 | 2018-06-17 14:00:00 | activity2      |             15 |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 12:00:00 | 2018-06-17 13:00:00 | activity1      |             20 |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 12:00:00 | 2018-06-17 13:00:00 | activity2      |             30 |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 12:00:00 | 2018-06-17 13:00:00 | activity3      |             05 |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 11:00:00 | 2018-06-17 12:00:00 | activity4      |             55 |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 10:00:00 | 2018-06-17 11:00:00 | activity5      |             30 |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 10:00:00 | 2018-06-17 11:00:00 | activity1      |             25 |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 09:00:00 | 2018-06-17 10:00:00 | activity4      |             15 |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 09:00:00 | 2018-06-17 10:00:00 | activity5      |             35 |
+----+-------+---------+------------------+-------+---------------+----------------+

TABLE2
+----+---------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+
|uid | user_name     | start_date_time     | parameter  | parameter_value |
+----+---------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+
| 01 | s01234        | 2018-06-17 11:35:26 | status     | B               |
| 01 | s01234        | 2018-06-17 11:35:26 | type       | GOLD            |
| 01 | s01234        | 2018-06-16 08:15:36 | status     | X               |
| 01 | s01234        | 2018-06-16 08:45:36 | type       | SILVER          |
| 02 | b23456        | 2018-06-16 13:00:00 | status     | A               |
| 02 | b23456        | 2018-06-16 13:00:00 | type       | SILVER          |
+----+---------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+
```

As you can tell in TABLE2 a record is maintained each time a parameter value changes.  I would like to return resultset from the 2 tables as follows:

```
EXPECTED RESULTSET
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|uid | active_hour_start   | active_hour_end     | activity_name  | activity_value | status         | type           |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 01 | 2018-06-17 13:00:00 | 2018-06-17 14:00:00 | activity1      |             10 | B              | GOLD           | 
| 01 | 2018-06-17 13:00:00 | 2018-06-17 14:00:00 | activity2      |             15 | B              | GOLD           |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 12:00:00 | 2018-06-17 13:00:00 | activity1      |             20 | B              | GOLD           |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 12:00:00 | 2018-06-17 13:00:00 | activity2      |             30 | B              | GOLD           |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 12:00:00 | 2018-06-17 13:00:00 | activity3      |             05 | B              | GOLD           |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 11:00:00 | 2018-06-17 12:00:00 | activity4      |             55 | X              | SILVER         |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 10:00:00 | 2018-06-17 11:00:00 | activity5      |             30 | X              | SILVER         |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 10:00:00 | 2018-06-17 11:00:00 | activity1      |             25 | X              | SILVER         |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 09:00:00 | 2018-06-17 10:00:00 | activity4      |             15 | X              | SILVER         |
| 01 | 2018-06-17 09:00:00 | 2018-06-17 10:00:00 | activity5      |             35 | X              | SILVER         |
+----+-------+---------+------------------+-------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Resultset contains all rows from TABLE1 for a given duration (based on a where clause on active_hour_start/active_hour_end) with 2 additional columns that contain the parameter name and value from TABLE 2 based start_date_time.

Thank You.

Comment: Just letting you know that you really ought to also show what you've tried so we know where you're stuck rather than just asking for an answer.

Comment: I have tried the following, but I know its not correct since conversion from rows to column can be done only on aggregate function.  So, need some help to identify how to transpose the rows to columns in this case and get the repeated values for parameter and value across each row.  

select t1.uid,t1.active_hour_start,t1.active_hour_end,t1.activity_name, t1.activity_value, if(t2.parameter='status',parameter_value,NULL),if(t1.parameter='type',parameter_value,NULL)
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.uid=t2.uid, t2.start_date_time>t1.active_hour_start

Answer (score 0):

Following query will return desired results.

```
select
table1.uid,table1.active_hour_end,table1.activity_name,
table1.activity_name,tab2.status,tab2.type
from
table1 
inner join
    (
        SELECT
            A.uid,
            A.username,
            A.start_date_time,
            St.Status,
            t.type 
        from
            (
                select distinct
                    uid,
                    user_name,
                    start_date_time 
                from
                    table2
            )
            A 
            INNER JOIN
                (
                    select
                        uid,
                        start_date_time,
                        parameter_value as Status 
                    from
                        table2 
                    where
                        parameter = 'status' 
                )
                ST 
                on (A.uid = ST.uid 
                and A.start_date_time = st.start_date_time ) 
            INNER JOIN
                (
                    select
                        uid,
                        start_date_time,
                        parameter_value as type 
                    from
                        table2 
                    where
                        parameter = 'type' 
                )
                T 
                on (A.uid = T.uid 
                and A.start_date_time = T.start_date_time ) 
    )
    tab2 
    on (table1.uid = tab2.uid 
    and tab2.start_date_time >= table1.active_hour_start 
    and start_date_time <= active_hour_end)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying.  Its returning only one row for the active_hour_start of 2018-06-17 11:00:00.  Will try to understand the joins and play around to see if it works for this use case.

Comment: can you just check by replacing last join condition by on (tab2.start_date_time>=table1.active_hour_start and table1.uid = tab2.uid)

Comment: It is returning 4 rows with the updated condition; however the status and type are incorrect.

Comment: please go through your expected result set there isn't any logic by which we can join tables so as to get specified result ..

Answer (score 0):

So far I have figured out the following solution .. might not be the most optimal solution, so if anyone has a better solution, please do post.

```
select t1.uid,t1.activity_name, t1.active_hour_start,
    (select parameter_value from table2 where parameter='status' and uid=t1.uid  and start_date_time<=t1.active_hour_start order by start_date_time desc limit 1)as status,
    (select parameter_value from table2 where parameter='type' and uid=t1.uid  and start_date_time<=t1.active_hour_start order by start_date_time desc limit 1)as type
from table1 t1
```